# Saving state of a specific like Button in recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In recycler view I have pictures with "Like" buttons on them. When I click a "Like" button for a specific picture, its color changes to red. But when I reopen the app, All "Like" buttons are red, even the ones which I didn't clicked.

I'm using sharedPreferences to save the state of the button.

In onBindViewHolder:

```
    myPref = context.getSharedPreferences("MINE", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    myEditor = myPref.edit();
    myEditor.putBoolean("isChecked", false);

    holder.likeBtn.setChecked(myPref.getBoolean("isChecked", false));

    holder.likeBtn.setOnCheckStateChangeListener((view, checked) -> {

        if (checked) {
            myEditor.putBoolean("isChecked", true);
            myEditor.apply();
            } else {
                myEditor.putBoolean("isChecked", false);
                myEditor.apply();
                    }
          }
```

So, here how can save clicked state of a specific like button. How can I get the position of a button that I want to click.

Comment: Why not have a boolean key in model and modify that?

Comment: @Daniyal Javaid Can you explain it in detail?